# Associate two gravatars images to one myOpenID account

Tags: support, gravatar, linked-accounts, myopenid

Can I link two grvatar images to one myOpenID account?

I have associated all my SUFO and stack exchange accounts to only myOpenID account.  I would like to use one image (my current image) for my gaming stack exchange account and use other image for all my accounts which is more appropriate for all the other sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Gravatar is linked to your email address, not your OpenId. So you just need a separate email address in your user profile.

Comment: I associated another e-mail address to myOpenID account.  How do I map that particular address to my gaming stack exchange account/

Comment: @Michael You don't have to do anything involving OpenId. All you need is a separate email address that you register with en.gravatar.com. Then, edit your profile field that says "email" to use that email address.

Comment: To add to this, if your email provider supports it (gmail does) you can create unique email addresses per site just by using the `+` suffix trick (so `user+SO@gmail.com` and `user+meta@gmail.com` are both aliases for `user@gmail.com`, but they're unique for gravatar purposes).